Unity Editor - [InitializeOnLoadMethod] Get executed multiple time in background
I've a weird issue in an Unity Editor script. I Created the code below as a minimal example to reproduce the issue, and the explanation of what's happening.
I'm using Unity version 2023.2.9f1
Script explanation
I've a static method that get executed when the Unity domain reload thanks to the [InitializeOnLoadMethod].It will create a file in the StreamingAssets folder. So far so good, when I open Unity I can see the logs being printed and a file is created in the StreamingAssets folder. Same things if I edit a script, this would trigger a Domain Reload and create a new file.
The Issue
I've had quite a hard time finding a way to replicate the issue every time but the following step seems to works :

Create a new Scene
Inspect the scene in the inspector windows.

When doing those step, the unity console doesn't show any new logs, but the SyncWriteFile() method does get executed twice again as I can see two new files being created. But this happen without a Domain Reload being explicitly trigger on the main Thread I think, otherwise the unity console should print the new logs. It's a big issue on my main project.
I think this is related to the AssetImportWorker, because when looking at the AssetImportWorkerX.log, first I can see 2 logs (AssetImportWorker0.log, AssetImportWorker1.log) and they do contains the Logging message of the two new file that were created.
Code and Logs
public static class TEST
{
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Init()
    {
        Debug.Log($"{DateTime.Now.Ticks} : INIT Start");

        AssemblyReloadEvents.afterAssemblyReload += AssemblyReloadEvents_afterAssemblyReload;
        SyncWriteFile();

        Debug.Log($"{DateTime.Now.Ticks} : INIT End");
    }

    private static void AssemblyReloadEvents_afterAssemblyReload()
    {
        Debug.Log($"{DateTime.Now.Ticks} : Assembly Reload");
    }

    private static void SyncWriteFile()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, $"test_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}");
        Debug.Log($"{DateTime.Now.Ticks} : Creating file {path}");
        File.Create(path);
    }
}



Does a sync method get executed only once?

You are right, a sync method does also get executed a new time. So this issue doesn't seems to be related to Async/Await but something about [InitializeOnLoadMethod] getting called a second time in the background. And I think it's related to the AssetImporter worker as the log displayed in unity doesn't match the one the AssetImportWorker.log. Which I Have two of those so it might come from here

what are all those warnings and errors? And what exactly should we be seeing in the image? As far as I can tell there is nothing logged twice ...

in general InitializeOnLoadMethod will be called each and every time script recompilation and thereby domain reload happens ...

I edited the post to match more closely to the issue after further investigation. The main problem reside in the fact that InitializeOnLoadMethod get called again not only when there is a domain reload, it seems to be called from another thread related to the AssetImporterWorker.

What's the question now? Since we know the method can be called more than once, is there a problem to have more files? Or do you want to report this as a bug? If you need an event related to compilation, you can try events in the CompilationPipeline class.

I don't see exactly what type of asset you create there .. some might very well cause a domain reload .. e.g. if it is some input actions or similar thing that generates code ... Or assembly definitions etc

derHugo Just looking at the code you would notice i create an empty file without extension... and I can confirm it wasn't causing a domain reload.
shingo Yes there is potentially a problem having a method that we expect to be executed only once but instead get executed 3 time (or more). I don't know though if this a bug or normal behaviors, but it ain't clearly explain anywhere I could search.

I finally found a solution but I'm not 100% sure why the issue happen in the first place. But first I would like to explain why this issue matter :
When developing an Editor Script, sometime there is a need to execute some initialisation code for example to setup a server, a task running in background etc... InitializeOnLoadMethod seems to be a good choice for that, I was using it in my project to setup an MQTT client and connect it to an MQTT Broker. I could then use the AssemblyReloadEvents.beforeAssemblyReload to safely dispose of the MQTT client and close the connection whenever I edit my script that would trigger a DomainReload.
BUT, as we saw, InitializeOnLoadMethod does get executed multiple time without a DomainReload and in separate threads, though creating multiple MQTT Client that kept living in those threads and were never safely dispose. Since they all had the same ClientID they were always kicking each other connection to the MQTT Broker as well... Eventually it was causing my Unity Editor to become totally unresponsive.
This is one example of issue that can arise from this but there are plenty more.
Solution
public static class TEST
{
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Boot()
    {
        //This event won't be fire in the AssetImporterWorker thread it seems
        EditorApplication.update += InitOnce;
    }

    private static void InitOnce()
    {
        EditorApplication.update -= InitOnce;
        //The code here will be executed only once every Domain Reload
        SyncWriteFile();
    }

    private static void SyncWriteFile()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, $"test_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}");
        Debug.Log($"{DateTime.Now.Ticks} : Creating file {path}");
        var fs = File.Create(path);
        fs.Close();
    }
}

Doesn't work
Some idea that I did try and didn't solved the issue :

Using a static bool to check if the method allready got executed, doesn't work because I think the AssetImporterWorker thread use different context
Using Unity SessionState to check is the method allready got executed, doesn't work for the same reason as above I think.
Putting the initialisation code in AssemblyReloadEvents.afterAssemblyReload doesn't work neither as this event get triggered in the AssetImporterWorker thread.


I'm a bit confused by the solution because if Boot as you claim actually gets executed twice then also the InitOnce would be subscribed twice and still fire twice right? As you create a file anyway .. couldn't you just check for the existence of that file? Unity does this themselves .. that's how they check if an instance of the project is already opened

I’m pretty sure this is expected behaviour. The InitializeOnLoad methods will fire on every reload of the Unity environment. This can be triggered by many things. This is also why your static variable solution didn’t work. The static variables will (usually) get wiped out whenever this occurs too. There are cases where static variables act strangely though in the editor.
To fix your issue, I might just check if the file already exists, if so overwrite, modify/ or do nothing depending on your needs.
If this doesn’t fulfill your needs you need to edit your question with more info on what the file is for and why you need it created in the first place.
